# looking up remote an EJB3 from a servlet with Jboss AS 7

Tags: java

Is that someone can tell me what's wrong in my program:
Remote EJB 3 was developed in BonjourEJB3 project. BonjourEJB3ClientWeb is a web client that calls the remote EJB3 project. I do not use Maven. 
Here's how I make my remote call:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String nom = request.getParameter("nom");
        String bonjour = "";

    Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
    jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");

    try {
        proxy = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
        bonjourBean = (BonjourService) proxy.lookup("java:global/BonjourEJB3/BonjourBean!com.quesnay.service.distant.BonjourService");
        if (nom != null) {
            bonjour = bonjourBean.ditBonjour(nom);          
        } 
        else {}
    }catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this is what turns me the Eclipse console :

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class com.quesnay.servlet.BonjourCamarade with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.BonjourEJB3ClientWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/quesnay/service/distant/BonjourService;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.quesnay.service.distant.BonjourService from [Module "deployment.BonjourEJB3ClientWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you're missing some classes in the EJB client.

Make sure that you have the latest version of ejb client jar and that the client contains the following class `com.quesnay.service.distant.BonjourService`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, in it there's already in the client jar project WEB-INF / lib / jboss-client.jar and jIn its classpath BonjourEJB3 the project. It's really a mystery why it does not work?

Comment: to be able to call EJB endpoint you need to have a client jar generated from the EJB endpoint. It's not enough to reference the whole project in the classpath.

Comment: So according to you is what I need to add or change? be more specific please